# ngx-print with custom css file

Tags: javascript, css, angular, printing

I am using ngx-print to perform the print action with css file, however, css is not working. Here is the example.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/demo-ngx-print-fmiwwr

Library reference.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print

```
<button printSectionId="demo"
styleSheetFile="assets/css/print.css"
 ngxPrint>print</button>
```

All the css are in the print.css file.

Answer (score 2):

please try to add [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-print) code, it works nicely for me

```
[useExistingCss]="true"
```

so it will be like this

```
<button [useExistingCss]="true" printSectionId="print-section" ngxPrint>print</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I could fix your example by updating the *`ngx-print`*

```json
"ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.5",
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.try to give the CSS file in the assets folder itself, it won't work when we give the CSS in any other file.solved my issue.

```
<button printSectionId="print-section" class="btn save" printTitle="printHeading" styleSheetFile="assets/css/print-pdf.css" [useExistingCss]="true" ngxPrint>Print</button>
```